# Jnius Android Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: java, python, android, bluetooth, kivy

I'm trying to create an Android app that communicates to a BLE Server. I'm writing it in python (using kivy and buildozer) and to access android java classes I use pyjnius.

So far I've been able to get the paired BT devices and check if their address matches the one I need. But as soon as I try to call the **'connectGatt()'** method, I get an error.

This method requires a **'BluetoothGattCalback'** object passed as an argument to handle all the events like **'onConnectionStateChange()'**.
After looking online, I found that someone has written an implementation of this class that should work with pyjnius.

However, after looking and following instructions on how to implement it, I get the following error:
***jnius.jnius.JavaException: No methods matching your arguments, available: ['(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;I)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;II)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;IILandroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;IZILandroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;']***

Here's the Java file (**'BluetoothGattImplem.java'**):

```java
    package org.test;
    
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
    import android.util.Log;
    
    public class BluetoothGattImplem extends BluetoothGattCallback {
    
          public interface OnBluetoothGattCallback {
           // ... all the methods from BluetoothGattCallback here ...like:
             void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic);
    
             void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState);
    
             void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status);
    
             void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status);
          
        }
        // private storage for the callback object
        private OnBluetoothGattCallback callback = null;
    
        // method to set the callback object
        public void setCallback(OnBluetoothGattCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            if (this.callback != null)
                this.callback.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic); 
        }
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (this.callback != null)
                this.callback.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState); 
        }
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (this.callback != null)
                this.callback.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status); 
        }
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            if (this.callback != null)
                this.callback.onCharacteristicRead(gatt,characteristic,status); 
        }
    }
```

Here's my implementation of the code in **'main.py'**:

```py
    from jnius import *
    
    PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
    Context = cast("android.content.Context", PythonActivity.mActivity)
    JBoolean = autoclass("java.lang.Boolean")
    UUID = autoclass("java.util.UUID")
    BluetoothDevice = autoclass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice")
    BluetoothAdapter = autoclass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter")
    BluetoothGATT = autoclass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt")
    BluetoothGATTCallback = autoclass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback")
    BluetoothGATTService = autoclass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService")
    BluetoothGATTCharacteristic = autoclass("android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic")
    BluetoothGATTImplement = autoclass("org.test.BluetoothGattImplem")
    
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    import android  
    
    def permissionCallback(permission, result):
        pass
    
    request_permissions([Permission.BLUETOOTH, Permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN], permissionCallback)
    
    class BLECallback(PythonJavaClass):
        __javainterfaces__ = ["org/test/BluetoothGattImplem$OnBluetoothGattCallback"]
        __javacontext__ = "app"
    
        @java_method("(Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;II)V")
        def onConnectionStateChange(self, gatt, status, newstate):
            pass
    
        @java_method("(Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic;I)V")
        def onCharacteristicRead(self, gatt, characteristic, state):
            pass
    
    pycallback = BLECallback()
    bg = BluetoothGATTImplement()
    bg.setCallback(pycallback)
    
    DEVICE_ADDRESS = "12:34:56:78"
    bl_adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    
    def bluetoothConnect():
            res = bl_adapter.getState()
            if res != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                return
            else:
                bl_devices = bl_adapter.getBondedDevices().toArray()
                for device in bl_devices:
                    if device.getAddress() == DEVICE_ADDRESS:
                        ### This is the line of code in which I get the error ###
                        bl_connection = device.connectGatt(Context, JBoolean(False), bg)
                        ###
```

Finally here is the **'buildozer.spec'**:

```
    [app]
    
    # (str) Source code where the main.py live
    source.dir = .
    
    # (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
    source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
    
    # (list) Application requirements
    # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
    requirements = python3,kivy,pyjnius
    
    # (list) List of service to declare
    #services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
    
    #
    # Android specific
    #
    
    # (list) Permissions
    #android.permissions = INTERNET
    android.permissions = BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, ACCES_FINE_LOCATION, ACCES_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
    
    # (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
    # directory containing the files)
    android.add_src = java/
    
    # (list) add java compile options
    # this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
    # see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
    # android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"
    
    # (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
    #android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity
    
    # (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
    # project.properties automatically.)
    #android.library_references =
    
    # (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
    android.arch = armeabi-v7a
```

Since I don't know much about Java and, therefore, its **packages**, I will also write down my directory structure:

```
    App/
    ├─ bin/
    ├─ java/
    │  ├─ org/
    │  │  ├─ test/
    │  │  │  ├─ BluetoothGattImplem.java
    │  │  │  ├─ MyBluetoothCallback.java
    ├─ buildozer.spec
    ├─ main.py
```

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, the only thing I want to achieve with the app is to connect to a BLE device and write (and possibly read) its characteristcs.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:**
As per request I trimmed to code to what I think is the bare minimum.

I also tried creating a new .java file that contained a class with a single attribute: a **BluetoothGattCallback object**. If I print the **connectGatt() arguments that I passed**, they return the correct objects, but I still get a similar error:

**jnius.jnius.JavaException: No methods matching your arguments, requested: (<android.content.Context at 0xd2629820 jclass=android/content/Context jself=<LocalRef obj=0x77ca at 0xb8424710>>, <java.lang.Boolean at 0xb84966b8 jclass=java/lang/Boolean jself=<LocalRef obj=0x753a at 0xd380fa90>>, <android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback at 0xb7d882d0 jclass=android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback jself=<LocalRef obj=0x7646 at 0xb8424cf0>>), available: ['(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;I)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;II)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;IILandroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;', '(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;IZILandroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;']**

As you can see, where it says **requested**, those are the arguments I passed, and they match with the first method in the **available** list, but still the app crashes with this error.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code and detailed information, do you need to just get the bluetooth info or do you need to have a server communicating similar to online gaming? If it's about info you could use plyer module https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plyer.facades.Bluetooth or you could also adapt the java classes needed using pyjnius but from the android developers docs based on the API level of the device https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview

Comment: @jbsidisJosuéCarranza In my app the smartphone will be a Gatt client, it has to write and read the charachteristics of a Gatt server. I did read the official docs, but when I tried to use the native **BluetoothGattCallback** class in pyjnius (with **PythonJavaClass**), I got an error that said that the object is not an interface. Plus I can't really code in Java, so adapting classes on my own isn't really an option for me, I was hoping I made a simple mistake that could be fixed easily.

Comment: Alright, I will review a little it bit more about it maybe I would find more info that could help to make this app to work, I will check if checking into an existing program (or app) that also uses Gatt has that implementation and if it does I will try to convert it into pyjnius python code, I will be using dex2jar

Comment: @jbsidisJosuéCarranza Thank you for you help and interest. In the meantime I've tried a few different things, like creating an instance of the native **BluetoothGattCallback** class but, since it is an abstract class, pyjnius doesn't allow that. I've tried changing name and directory of my .java implementation, but with no luck. I also reseache if in Java it is possible to pass a subclass instance as an argument that requires the superclass and it should be possible. Maybe pyjnius does a check before calling methods? I have no idea.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Community Hi, I trimmed the code a bit, this is the minimum code that should work.

Comment: I have been looking for more info, I have not been able to do it by myself but I found this documents that may help you to build the app with the functions, you can check here https://able.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: @jbsidisJosuéCarranza Hi, thanks again. I did find this module a few days ago and I've worked a bit on it. I still can't make it work yet, but I have to study it a bit